# Finding dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients and having
degree at most $20$.
 Define the subspaces

$W_1 = \{p \in V : p(1) = 0,\ p(1/2)= 0,\ p(5) = 0,\ p(7) = 0\}$,

$W_2 = \{p \in V : p(1/2)=0,\ p(3) = 0,\ p(4) = 0,\ p(7) = 0\}$

Then find dimensions of $W_1,\ W_2$ and $W_1\cap W_2$.

If possible please refer appropriate books for these types of questions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Unfortunately, nearly all of the mathematics in this post isn't displaying for me (and I assume I'm not alone). Thankfully, it's possible to be understood using [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), although there is a learning curve initially.

Comment: I need answer to this question urgently.
Please help

Comment: Hey Katherine. Problems like this are usually seen in elementary linear algebra texts, often in the exercises sections but also in examples. http://linear.ups.edu/ is one such book. Lay is another.

Comment: @Katherine: This is not the sort of site where we do your homework for you. Please indicate what you've tried so far and what you're stuck on. This looks like a standard elementary linear algebra problem; what have you covered in class that would be relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the polynomials in $W_1$ has obligatorily 5 roots, so the polynomials with
degree less than 5 is not in $W_1$. The polynomials
$$
 w(x) = (x-1)(x-1/2)(x-5)(x-7)x^\alpha, \qquad \alpha = 0, \; 1, \;2, \dots 16
$$
are a basis for $W_1$. Thus, $\dim(W_1) = 17$.

The same idea can be use to $W_2$. For $W_1 \cap W_2$, first we observe that
$$
 W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ p \in V \,: \; p(1/2) = 0, \; p(1) = 0, \; p(3) = 0, \; p(4)= 0, \; p(5) = 0, \; p(7) = 0\}.
$$
Then, by the same argument, $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = 15$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that $V$ has the basis $\{1,x,\dots ,x^{20}\}$. It's also clear that $V$ is a unique factorization domain, i.e. for any $f \in V$ we $f = f_1 \dots f_n$ for some $n$ and each $f_j$ a non-constant irreducible polynomial. Finding bases for $W_1$ and $W_2$ simply amounts to putting restrictions on our basis for $V$. For $g \in W_1$, $$g(x) = (x-1/2)(x-1)(x-5)(x-7)f_1\dots f_n$$ Since $g$ must have degree $\leq 20$, $f_1\dots f_n$ must have degree $\leq 16$. Thus we can find a basis for $W_1$ : $\{(x-1/2)(x-1)(x-5)(x-7)x^j : 0 \leq j \leq 16\}$ The same argument can be done for $W_2$ and $W_1\cap W_2$ (after you have properly defined $W_1\cap W_2$).

An approachable book for learning linear algebra is "Linear algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler.