# why $ W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ p \in V \,: \; p(1/2) = 0, \; p(1) = 0, \; p(3) = 0, \; p(4)= 0, \; p(5) = 0, \; p(7) = 0\}. ?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients and having
degree at most $20$.
Define the subspaces

$W_1 = \{p \in V : p(1) = 0,\ p(1/2)= 0,\ p(5) = 0,\ p(7) = 0\}$,

$W_2 = \{p \in V : p(1/2)=0,\ p(3) = 0,\ p(4) = 0,\ p(7) = 0\}$

Then find the dimensions of $W_1\cap W_2?$.

I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1353488/1051300)

Also  i didn't comment  below on that answer because   that user last seen was more than 4 years  ago

**My  question** : why $$
 W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ p \in V \,: \; p(1/2) = 0, \; p(1) = 0, \; p(3) = 0, \; p(4)= 0, \; p(5) = 0, \; p(7) = 0\}.
?$$

**My thinking** :I think  $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{ p \in V \,: \; p(1/2) = 0, \; p(7) = 0\}$ because  here  only  two constrainst are common i.e $p(1/2) $ and $p(7) \in  W_1$ and  $W_2$    remaining   constraint   are not common

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about $W_1\cap W_2$, so a vector in this space must satisfy **both** constraints of $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: I think  by the definition of Venn diagram you are  wrong because the intersection of sets for two given sets is the set that contains all the elements that are common to both sets.

Comment: @wasiu If $a$ is a common element of $W_1$ and $W_2$, then $a$ should satisfy the constraints in $W_1$, and the constraints in $W_2$.

Comment: ..@Suanders  but $p(1)  , p(5) \notin W_2$

Comment: A polynomial $p \in W_1$ must satisfy all of the conditions for being in $W_1$, and a polynomial $p \in W_2$ must satisfy all of the conditions for being in $W_2$. Hence, if $p\in W_1 \cap W_2$, i.e. $p \in W_1$ **and** $p \in W_2$, then $p$ must have the constraints for being in both. It is not the constraints that must be combined for the intersection, but rather the lists of constraints for **both** sets all individually must be satisfied.

Comment: Bear in mind $p(1)$ is not an element of $W_2$. It is a constraint. The problem is saying "if $p$ is in $W_2$, then $p(1) = 0$," and the same is true of the various other conditions.

Comment: okay @PrincessEev

Comment: For instance, more concretely and away from more abstract mathematics, define

$$\begin{align*}
A &:= \{\text{all objects which are blue and striped}\} \\
B &:= \{\text{all objects which are blue and cubical}\}
\end{align*}$$

or, perhaps more in the spirit of the problem,

$$\begin{align*}
A &:= \{x \in \text{objects} \mid\text{color}(x) = \text{blue} \;,\; \text{pattern}(x) = \text{striped}\} \\
B &:= \{x \in \text{objects} \mid \text{color}(x) = \text{blue} \;,\; \text{shape}(x) = \text{cube}\} 
\end{align*}$$

[cont.]

Comment: Your logic incorrectly suggests that

$$\begin{align*}
A \cap B 
&= \{\text{all objects which are blue}\} \\
&= \{x \in \text{objects} \mid \text{color}(x) = \text{blue} \} 
\end{align*}$$

but, this is wrong, since $A \cap B$ may have objects which are blue but not striped (and thus not in $A$), or blue but not cubical (and thus not in $B$). 

[cont.]

Comment: Since $A \cap B$ is meant to be all items which are in $A$ **and also in** $B$, the true answer would be

$$\begin{align*}
A \cap B 
&= \{\text{all objects which are simultaneously blue, striped, and cubical}\} \\
&= \{x \in \text{objects} \mid \underbrace{\text{color}(x) = \text{blue} \;,\; \text{pattern}(x) = \text{striped} \;,\; \text{shape}(x) = \text{cube}}_{\text{all three of these constraints must be true!}}\} \\
\end{align*}$$

Hopefully that clears up any unnecessary confusion. The constraints in this case are just "what values do these polynomials take on?"

Comment: thanks You  Now got  it @PrincessEev You   can write these  comments on answer box